# Visual Studio new set up that fails to launch code after successful build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

Here is the error from the VS output window.

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework

```
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.1.27 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      3.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      3.1.14 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
      5.0.5 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
```

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
The specified framework can be found at:

- https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=2.2.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64

The browser loads the following.

HTTP Error 502.5 - ANCM Out-Of-Process Startup Failure
Common solutions to this issue:
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681

I have tried the links and installed several version of .net core and .net 5.0. I have reinstalled Visual Studio. I have removed Microsoft.AspnetCore via nuget and reinstalled. At this point I can't figure out what I am missing. It could be something simple I have missed, so feel free to give suggestions. The error messages have not change at all.

This issue occurred after losing access to development platform in the cloud that had no issues and setting up a VS community Ed. working local on my laptop. Also tried a new web application and had no issues. Application is extremely large so upgrading all the code to .net core 3.1 is a major undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try different browser - on the page pointed by your first link there is direct link: [aspnetcore-runtime-2.2.0](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/70800ed3-22cd-4111-9e00-e9fc3535d5c6/f7b76341e582f3a8952b7fdec06e0646/aspnetcore-runtime-2.2.0-win-x86.exe) to the "ASP.NET Core 2.2 Runtime (v2.2.0) - Windows x86 Installer" in my case - Firefox 88.0.1 - I could load the file without any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it didn't help. I need the x64 version, but couldn't figure out the url to find it. What page did you find the link on?

Answer (score 0):

The resolve was to download dotnet-sdk-2.2.100-win-x64 and move it into C:\Program Files\dotnet. I had to specifically move the Microsoft.AspNetCore.ALL & Microsoft.AspNetCore.App & Microsoft.NETCore.ALL folders into shared. I also had to move folder 2.2.0 into C:\Program Files\dotnet\host\fxr. I also had to move folder 2.2.100 into C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk.

I had loaded donet-sdk-2.2.8, but that failed. I am not sure why it required manual movement of folders into the C:\Program Files\dotnet.